# Slowly changing dimension Type 2 with Version ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse

I'm trying to implement this functionality with different tables related to be able to have a historical report at the end.

At the first time I suppose to have a baseline information on my historical tables. Here some information

```
**EmployeeHistory:**

id  Number  OrgId   AccountId   VersionId   Date
1   34343   1       1           1           2010-01-01


**OrganizationHistory:**

OrgId   Name    VersionId   Date
1       Sales   1           2010-01-01


**AccountHistory:**

AccountId   Name    VersionId   Date
1           ABC     1           2010-01-01


**Final Employee Report:**

id  Number  OrgId   AccountId   Date
1   34343   Sales   ABC         2010-01-01
```

I'm using a VersionId (in this case equal to 1) that will helps me to retrieve the data at specific time. Any change will insert on record on the table and increase the VersionId by 1 so let's say now I changed the AccountId name, I will have a new record on my Account table:

```
AccountId   Name    VersionId    Date
1           ABC     1            2010-01-01
1           ABB     2            2010-01-02
```

Ok now I'm going to change the Employee number

```
id  Number  OrgId   AccountId   VersionId   Date
1   34343   1       1           1           2010-01-01
1   34355   1       1           2           2010-01-03
```

For each individual table it's fine, I can easily retrieve the data order by Date plus VersionId because I can have many changes on the same day.

My question is how can I retrieve accurately my Employee Report starting from my EmployeeHistory table drilling down the rest of the tables? By Versionid is not possible because versionId is independent and different for each table, by date either because I guess is going to be slow and if I have many changes on the same day, I should probably add the condition with the latest versionid.

Any idea or good example to resolve this?

Comment: What facts do these join to? You join these to a fact based on the surrogate key then use dates in the fact to filter

Comment: but I need to connect these three tables together to get the whole information from each entity and besides each entity can be modified. How the surrogate will help me on this.The fact is to join those tables to get the names instead of the ids

Comment: _how can I retrieve accurately my Employee Report starting from my EmployeeHistory table drilling down the rest of the tables_. Are you saying: "given a single employee id record, show me the organization and account details valid at that time"? I don't understand your requirements. If you have multiple versions of employees on a given day , and multiple versions of organizations on the same day, there is *no* way to associated given versions. You don't have enough information in your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a proper dimensional model, your dimension rows should be identified by a surrogate key. You're mixing up the concepts of dimension key, business key and version, which is why you are having problems with the modelling.

You're also missing a fact table, as others have noted. You might have a situation known as a "factless fact", which is where the fact table only serves to establish the relationship between the dimensions, and has no measures recorded for the fact.

I think your model should look something like this:

```
employment_factless_fact (dim_emp_id, dim_org_id, dim_acc_id)

dim_employee (dim_emp_id,emp_id,...)

dim_organisation (dim_ord_id,org_id,org_name,from_date,to_date,...)

dim_account (dim_acc_id,acc_id,acc_name,from_date,to_date,...)
```

The difference between dim_x_id and x_id is that dim_x_id is the surrogate key and x_id is the business key. My business key never changes, but I'll have a different surrogate value each time something about me (ie, name) changed. I've only used this naming convention to illustrate the model, I wouldn't recommend it in practice.

Comment: Ok thanks, so If I implement this logic, how can I retrieve the data based on this model starting from employee ?

Comment: Create a join like this:

select *
from employee_factless_fact eff
join dim_employee e on e.dim_emp_id = eff.dim_emp_id
where e.emp_id = 12345

This is the 'star' in 'star schema'. Your fact table is the center of the query, then join your dimension tables, then apply the where clause that gives you the data you want.

Does that make sense? It is difficult to show queries in comments :)

Answer (score 0):

The following query would give you employee changes ordered by ascending order of Number and descending order of VersionId on any particular date

```
SELECT EH.*
  FROM EmployeeHistory EH
 INNER 
  JOIN (
         SELECT OH.OrgId
              , OH.Date
              , MAX(OH.VersionId) AS VersionId
           FROM OrganizationHistory OH
          GROUP
             BY OH.OrgId, OH.Date
       ) O
    ON EH.OrgId = O.OrgId
   AND EH.Date = O.Date
 INNER
  JOIN (
         SELECT AH.AccountId
              , AH.Date
              , MAX(AH.VersionId) AS VersionId 
           FROM AccountHistory AH 
          GROUP 
             BY AH.AccountId
              , AH.Date
       ) A
    ON EH.AccountId = A.AccountId
   AND EH.Date = A.Date
 WHERE EH.Date = "2010-01-01"
 ORDER
    BY EH.Number ASC
      ,EH.VersionID DESC
```

The sub-query for account gets the latest records for accounts (AccountId) based on VersionId for all Dates. The sub-query for organization does the same for organizations.

Hope this helps..